# Increase values stored in continuous memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I allocated an array of `int16_t` of size `SIZE` like following.

```
#define SIZE 1152

int16_t *samples = malloc(sizeof(int16_t) * SIZE);
```

Now I can set these values to zero as following.

```
memset(samples, 0, sizeof(int16_t) * SIZE);
```

Is there a way to increase/decrease values stored in `samples` by certain amount with a single operation (similar to `memset`) and **not by looping** through every single element of the array?

It's C code processing audio intended for Android, if it's important.

**Update:** I'm going to use [NEON instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0002a/ch01s04s02.html) for ARM. They allow to execute on operation on a vector of data in parallel.

Comment: Write a loop. Wrap it in a function calleed "memadd". Done...

Comment: @keshlam This is audio processing. Looping in very slow...

Comment: I don´t think  you can "batch-increase" some data with standard processor instructions. And Android devices are unlikely to have something suited for this (PC graphic cards are probably a good example of devices which will surely support that.)

Comment: @jeffamaphone I expect some optimizations depending on the platform, and not just a loop...

Comment: So, you are trying to batch increase to the same value?? Do all of them have the same value or different?? If same, then why not `memset(samples, no+1, sizeof(int16_t) * SIZE);` for all the block.

Comment: @brokenfoot there can be different values stored in array

Comment: @brokenfoot: Because there could be different value in each array element? "Each element +2" does not mean that the results will be all the same

Comment: Ohkay.. I thought these are the same values incremented to the same no..My bad!

Comment: There's a framework http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/orc/ which allows cpu-independent vector processing routines (compiled in run time to exploit sse, avr, or neon) that are emulated in environments without those features. IMO the overhead is substantial, but not as bad as using vector intrinsics.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it in one instruction. There is no such Assembler instruction so you have to loop. If you write your loop in pure asm it can be really small and fast.
But any decent compiler should have optimization switch which generally works good.

Answer (score 1):

Memset is a loop too, you know. There's no magic here.

Well-written C should compile and optimize to not be much slower than hand-written assembler.

```
 int i=length_of_array;
 while(--i>=0)
    samples[i]+=offset;
```

Comment: Just wondering whether there can be special processor's instructions for such operations?

Comment: Can there be? Sure. Are there? Rarely, unless you're talking about a vector processor like those in the graphic engines; adding a constant to a vector *is* a common operation for them.

On the other hand, with modern scalar processors it's possible that the fetch/add/write cycle is already being overlapped in the hardware without your being aware of it or needing to use a special instruction for the purpose.

Comment: Just found Neon instructions extension for ARM which can be used on Android. Going to try it out. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0002a/ch01s04s02.html